# Edit raw HTML of the landing page

Tags: themes, html, customization

I just created and set up a landing page for my blog. I use Weaver theme.

I checked every checkbox to remove all the stuff I don't want ( `Hide Page Title,   Hide Site Title/Description,   Hide Menus,   Hide Standard Header Image` etc) and set page template to `Blank`.

In fact I don't want **any** foreign stuff in my pure html+css+js page but it's not as easy as it seems.

Maybe there's a php file somewhere in wordpress' folders corresponding to my page I can edit?

Answer (score 1):

It is very strange to me that you are using WordPress and want a "pure html+css+js page". That sort-of defeats the purpose of using WordPress, and honestly building with PHP is so much more convenient and powerful that I never want pure HTML anymore.

But here is how to do it...

You could dig through your theme and find the file responsible, but you'd be hacking the theme and you would lose the changes when the theme updates. Instead, create a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template) and ***leave out*** `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` so that all you have is this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/
?>
<html>
<!-- etc -->
</html>
```

Now go to the admin screens, create a page, and [select your template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Selecting_a_Page_Template). Then go to Settings -> Reading and [select your page as the static front page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen).

If your theme does not already have a [`front-page.php` file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Front_Page_display) you could use that but how that template loads can be confusing. I'd consider the first method more bullet-proof if you are not already familiar with theme creation.